# CSS only way of defining rule that is only applied on elements of a certain width?

Tags: javascript, css

Currently I listen to the resize event using javascript and apply a css class to my layout depending on how wide it is.

```
eg: <800px --> <div class="layout" />
    >800px --> <div class="layout wide" />
```

This works, but feels clunky.

I am wondering if there is a css-only way of defining rules that are only applied if an element is a certain width / size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what media queries are for, however they apply to the viewport as a whole rather than individual elements. So you might have this:

```
.layout {
    /* styles for wide layout */
}
@media all and (max-width:800px) {
    .layout {
        /* styles for narrow layout */
    }
}
```

Comment: good to know, thanks.  Do you know if there is anyway to have the rule applied based on the width of the element, as opposed to the viewport?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there isn't. Javascript would be your only option there, but keep in mind that if you apply styles that way it may stop the width from updating properly.